# Probability involving unions and intersections

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Out of a group of people, 60% like Vegetables, 70% like Chocolate, and 40% like vegetables and chocolate. Find the probability that a randomly selected person in the group neither likes Vegetables nor Chocolate.

$P(V)=0.60,$ $P(C)=0.70,$ and $P(V \cap C)=0.40$

Is this equivalent to saying $P(not(likes \; Vegetables \; OR \;Chocolate))?$

Hence $P(V^c \cap C^c)?$

Then $P(V^c \cap C^c)= P(V^c)+P(C^c)-P(V^c \cup C^c)$

Where the superscript c is the complement of each event?

Is my logic flawed?

Thanks in advance for any advice or hints.

Comment: Why the down vote?  I showed work or at least my ideas without just expecting an answer.

Comment: I don't understand either, I upvoted your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seem OK, but not the most direct route to the answer.
$P(V\cup C) = .6 + .7 - .4 = .9$
Then explain why to subtract from 1 for $P[(V \cup C)^c].$

Comment: I got 0.1 when I simplified my overcomplicated expression.  $P(A^c)=1-P(A).$  Thank you for your help!